# Makefile does not produce the expected file output

Tags: c++, makefile

I have the following Makefile which I mostly copied over from a different Makefile and slightly adjusted.  For some reason it is doing some pretty weird things:
**1)** when I run make, I do not get the executable file '*execute*' rather I get out *a.out*, which I have no idea why.
**2)** I'm not getting back *a 'make: Nothing to be done for `all'.'* when I make it back to back (implying that nothing was changed therefore it does not need to be updated, hence the purpose in my opinion of a Makefile).  If I make it back to back I get

```
    g++ stern_sim.o mag_cur_loop.o thetaddotMotion.o
```

which I thought implies that it is still trying to update it.  And once again every time I end up with an *a.out* instead of a *execute*.  Anyways, so help on those two questions would be great.  Also, all the indents are using the tab, no spaces (I doubled and triple checked).

```
CC= g++
CFLAGS= -c -Wall -lm -std=c++0x
SHELL:=/bin/bash

all: execute

execute: stern_sim.o mag_cur_loop.o thetaddotMotion.o
        $(CC) stern_sim.o mag_cur_loop.o thetaddotMotion.o

stern_sim.o: stern_sim.cpp
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) stern_sim.cpp

mag_cur_loop.o: mag_cur_loop.cpp
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) mag_cur_loop.cpp

thetaddotMotion.o: thetaddotMotion.cpp
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) thetaddotMotion.cpp

clean:
        rm -rf *.o execute
```

Comment: `execute` is not the name of the executable, but the name of the rule `make` use to concatenate your objects files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`a.out` is the default name for executables produced by C and C++ on unix-like platforms, for historical reasons. If you want to call the executable something else, you need to use the `-o`  linker option:

```
$(CC) stern_sim.o mag_cur_loop.o thetaddotMotion.o -o execute
```

though I would say that `execute` is  probably an extremely bad name for an executable.